# Java - Simple plane of inclusion/exclusion

Tags: java, math, graphics, 3d, space

This may have been answered before, and if so, point me to the answer. Otherwise, here goes.

You have x number of objects in space, which have bounding coordinates p0 and p1. p0 and p1 are each 3 dimensional coordinates and p0 always has the lower values - whether negative or positive, and p1 always has the higher values.

Now, you have a plane, which is perfectly orthogonal to the direction of camera C, which has a position (pC) and a heading (hC). This plane can then be defined as being 90 degrees (pi/2 radians) from the camera's yaw (sometimes called 'heading') and pitch and extending unto the furthest defined bounds in the space.

Because I do not permit more than 180 degrees FOV, anything which lies completely behind the camera (behind the plane of exclusion) must be excluded.

Is there a simple way to do this? For this question, I do not treat the issue of having to check against every object in the space; assume for the purpose of our question that there are always a limited number of objects - managed by partitioning the space in some fashion - so that the objects we check against are always 'questionable'.

Also keep in mind that because these are not points but pairs of points representing 3d bounding cubes, it is not enough for a point to lie on this or that side of the plane.

I get the feeling there is a simple way to do this, but not having taken Computer Graphics I was never introduced to the math.

Comment: I suspect a better place for this question would be in http://math.stackexchange.com (Math forum) or alternatively http://cs.stackexchange.com (CompSci forum)

Comment: Maybe, though this is not a theoretical question, but a practical one. So it's not strictly a math question or a computer science question but a java question. Because the problem needs to be solved in Java! I just phrased it in a general way to make sure I don't get the answer 'you're representing these in the wrong way...'

Comment: Fair point, however if an algorithm is defined in mathematical terms, then you can implement it in any language you like. (By the way, I did get my Master's degree in computer graphics - 15 years ago - but can't remember anything useful anyway :) )

Comment: Well, I'm hoping by the time I've written the OctTree I'll have an answer ;)

Comment: They would boot this question from either math.SE or cs.SE so fast your head would spin.  Maybe gamedev.SE?

Comment: We can just keep it here and answer it since it is kind of a vague area. Simulators are not necessarily games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's how to do it.

First you need to store the eight points in each bounding box in a predictable manner, for instance, each bit in an integer representing its position about the center of the box. What you can do is use 0x4 to represent EAST (+x) (zero in that bit means WEST) 0x2 to represent NORTH (zero in that bit means SOUTH) and 0x1 to represent TOP (zero in that bit means BOTTOM). Now you can universally access all points in the same position of the bounding box by specifying a position number. (all zero bit numbers are just zero. Java warns that these assignments are meaningless, but they help with readability.)

Setting up the bounding box: (do this for every bounding box)

```
    pointList = new Point3d[8];

    pointList[WEST|SOUTH|BOTTOM] = new Point3d(x0,y0,z0);
    pointList[WEST|SOUTH|TOP]    = new Point3d(x0,y0,z1);
    pointList[WEST|NORTH|BOTTOM] = new Point3d(x0,y1,z0);
    pointList[WEST|NORTH|TOP]    = new Point3d(x0,y1,z1);
    pointList[EAST|SOUTH|BOTTOM] = new Point3d(x1,y0,z0);
    pointList[EAST|SOUTH|TOP]    = new Point3d(x1,y0,z1);
    pointList[EAST|NORTH|BOTTOM] = new Point3d(x1,y1,z0);
    pointList[EAST|NORTH|TOP]    = new Point3d(x1,y1,z1);
```

Next, calculate the normal from your view angle. (Yaw is left/right rotation, pitch is up/down rotation)

```
    float nx = -(float)Math.cos(yaw);
    float ny = (float)Math.sin(yaw);
    float nz = (float)Math.sin(pitch);
```

I think the negative is right, but if everything is invisible on one side, just reverse it :)

Calculate the Characteristic Point, which is just the index that you're going to check in every bounding box because it represents the point in every box that will be nearest to the plane on the invisible side:

```
    int characteristicPoint = (nx<0?WEST:EAST)|
                              (ny<0?SOUTH:NORTH)|
                              (nz<0?BOTTOM:TOP);
```

Make sure that every bounding box is set up such that x,y,z aught are lesser than x,y,z prime (x0 = x aught, x1 = x prime)

Then collect your characteristic ('check') point, your set of normals ('frustrum'), and your camera position (x,y,z) and do this with every bounding box:

```
    float checkA = ((bounds.pointList[check].x-position.x)*frustrum.x) +
            ((bounds.pointList[check].y-position.y)*frustrum.y);

    float checkB = ((bounds.pointList[check].x-position.x)*frustrum.x) +
            ((bounds.pointList[check].z-position.z)*frustrum.z);
    if(checkB>=0&&checkA>=0) {
        visible = true;
        return;
    } else if(checkB<0&&checkA<0) {
        visible = false;
        return;
    } else {
       float checkC = ((bounds.pointList[check].y-position.y)*frustrum.y) +
            ((bounds.pointList[check].z-position.z)*frustrum.z);
       if(checkC>=0) {
          visible = true;
          return;
       } else {
          visible = false;
          return;
       }

    }
```

This is simple linear algebra (IMO) and the logic is as follows: If the point is on the positive side of two or more of the lines representing the plane, it is visible. If it is on the negative side of tow or more of the lines representing the plane, it is invisible. You calculate the first two, and if they are different (one negative, one positive) you check the third and take that value.

It is important to note the following property when treating lines as equations:

```
-x-y = p != x+y = p
```

The line is the same, but its implicit 'facing' is inverse.

I hope this helps someone else with this question. It was hard, but enjoyable, to figure out.

This could be made more efficient by storing the first half of CheckA, I suppose :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to find the set of pairs of points where both points are behind the camera plane (which I think you're describing as a normal 2d plane containing the point pC and with normal hC), but I may have misunderstood.

If that is what you want, then try this:

- hC is your plane normal
- set vp0 as the vector from pC to p0 (do position of p0 - position of pC)
- set vp1 as the vector from pC to p1 (do position of p1 - position of pC)

p0 is visible if vp0 . hC >= 0 (or > 0 if you want it to have to be strictly infront of the camera).

p1 is visible if vp1 . hC >= 0 (or > 0 if you want it to have to be strictly infront of the camera).

. here is a standard vector dot product.

So if both p0 and p1 are behind the camera you can exclude the shape.

Comment: +1, this is pretty much what I was typing. @RiverC the only math you are missing is the standard terminology; you have the concepts down. Your camera 'position' and 'heading' together define a **plane** in terms of **a point on it** and its **normal**.

Comment: One problem. consider the case the camera sitting at p0 or p1 and facing perpendicular to the line formed by p0,p1. (P). While both p0 and p1 may lie behind the plane, part of the bounding cube will still lie on the inclusion side of the plane. Any simple way to resolve this, or will I need all eight points instead of just two?

(generally, I just need to figure out how much math it takes to figure out at what geometry complexity level it is worth doing this)

Comment: I think you either want to know all 8 points of the bounding cube and test each of them, or possibly find a 3d space transformation matrix and apply that to all of the points so that the axis are either parallel or perpendicular to the viewing plane. Then you can probably stick to two points on your bounding cubes. I doubt that's an efficient way of doing it though.

Answer (score 1):

If any of the 6 corners of the "cube" (conventionally known as an Axis-Aligned Bounding Box, or AABB) is on the view side of the plane, it might be possible to see something inside it.  You can start by checking the two initial points, but if they are both invisible, you will also need to check the other six corners, as follows:

```
initial corners: p0=(p0.x, p0.y, p0.z)
                 p1=(p1.x, p1.y, p1.z)

other corners:      (p1.x, p0.y, p0.z)
                    (p0.x, p1.y, p0.z)
                    (p0.x, p0.y, p1.z)

                    (p1.x, p1.y, p0.z)
                    (p0.x, p1.y, p1.z)
                    (p1.x, p0.y, p1.z)
```

Note that the conventional rasterization pipeline shouldn't draw objects behind the camera, because it clips triangles that fall outside the [viewing frustum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viewing_frustum).  This suggests you may want to test against the other frustum planes as well, or perhaps against the viewing frustum as a whole, which is a bit more complex, but probably a good idea.  It may seem tedious, but a frustum test will still be cheaper than trying to draw invisible objects.

Comment: Right, though ultimately if you're using partitioned space - if the bounding boxes represent complex groups of data (they will!) you want to make sure you don't waste cycles sending ~1000 faces+ to the renderer when you could do a couple of checks against the bounding boxes of the partitions and eliminate them from the renderlist that frame.

My main point here is given my view angles and position, combined with a collection of p0,p1 pairs, what do I actually need to do in Java to 'black out' each bounding box?

Comment: To check vs. a plane, you need to make sure all 8 corners are on the invisible side of the plane.  To check vs. a viewing frustum is a bit more complex, but it should be better to do it all at once.  Google "AABB frustum" -- I haven't found a definitive link, but still worth checking it out.

Comment: aw yiss, I figured it out myself. I was hoping to avoid understanding this madness, but I somehow did it.